# Minimizing number of vertices in models for usage in games

Tags: vertices

relatively new to blender and modeling in general. So for starters I have been trying to create a few building/store models to import to unity to use. In blender my models show about 2k tries and verts. When I import they are well over 30k!! Now, me being new I am sure there is something I am doing incorrectly. I have tried different methods of uv unwrapping as lately tried creating all my store exterior as a normals map but all I get is a flat image of the shapes. These models are for mobile platform and I have read for those that 30k is about max per camera view so these models are useless as of now. It is a small town scene. These buildings need an interior and exterior. So my question is.. is it possible to make a high poly version and bake textures, normals and light maps onto a low poly cube or similar to get my detailed exterior? If not, what is some methods I can approach to hit around 1k verts and tris when imported? My models are simply designed by extruded planes to create the walls - subdivided and extruded/ inset to make windows and doors. Windows remain solid but I do cut sections for walk in doors. I use remove doubles, limited desolve and decimate modifiers but still the same. I'm stumped. I see mobile games like order and chaos for example, have massive towns that appear to be tons of verticies. I'm a hobbiest who does this in spare time as I am a truck driver and don't have hours on end for extensive tutorial watching. Thanks for reading! I will try to upload some images later of a model to show my failed attempts. Any constructive advice and tips greatly appreciated :)

Update:

Note: some is triangulated but even when I remove them it still imports to unity with over 30k verts and 8k tris
Attached a simple version with texture and a version of wireframe.
[image: Wire Frame]
[image: Preview with texture - not full texture render just idea]

Comment: Have you tried removing doubles in edit mode? That might reduce it some.

Comment: Are you using any subsurf modifiers? Subsurf will create a lot of geometry in no time.

Comment: You might consider to learn no retopology (to lower your polycount). Afterwards, you bake your colour map, normal map, displacement map, etc from your high poly models to your low poly models. If you apply the kind of maps/textures to your low poly models, they will look high poly. See these 2 videos, so you understand better what i'm saying:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzXNZkEoTAk and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W07H7xeUnGE and on baking:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU

Comment: After you IV unwrap both the high and low poly versions of your building, you need to bake the normals, ambient occlusions, and displacements from high poly to low poly textures. I've only dabbled a bit with this. I'd recommend checking out a small part of one of Darrin Lille's YouTube tutorials for how to do this. Look for the character modeling teen goblin series. Just after he retopologizes the character he starts baking out normals from his high poly to low poly meshes... look there.

Comment: Here's the video I mentioned... https://youtu.be/wN7I24t8Oec be sure to add the baked textures to the materials for the low poly models.

Comment: Yes I have been removing doubles in edit mode. Have not added any sun surface modifiers. I will look at those videos and try learning retopology. Thanks so much for the fast replies. I'll work on this later and see how it turns out. Thanks again!

Comment: If Blender shows you 2k tris for object and after importing into engine you get 30k for that same object retopology won't help you much, it's something happening while exporting - either hidden mesh revealing or something else. Make sure that there aren't any hidden objects, that all 3d layers are visible etc. Or export only selected object and look up if it's the same as in Blender.

Comment: I checked the export and there are no hidden meshes or objects that I could find. I am going to take screenshots of the mesh and object now and see if you guys can spot anything I am missing as a rookie :P

Comment: Did you export **only** the low poly model? If you export both objects, you will still have the high poly count.

Comment: This  model here is just one model that I did before getting the idea of low poly/ high poly and it is only one modeled mesh. With this particular one you can see the vert and tri count but is wayyy higher in unity in the 30ks when I remove shadows, etc. So this image shown is ONE model and ONE mesh in scene. No normal mapping or anything just a straight forward model.

Comment: Well, this seems to be more question to game engine as it deals with real time rendering. E.g. for Unity - https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-multiplying-my-poly-count.50576 and http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8969/why-is-there-such-a-huge-disparity-in-polycount-be.html, it will count vertex located on a seam as 2 vertices as it technically splits the mesh to flatten it on the texture. And this is only one example. Although - 2k and 30k imo is still too big difference.

Comment: You can, of course, have as many disconnected meshes in an object as you like, but If you have a high poly model, it has to be a separate object than the low poly object, or you can't export one without the other. Also I think you need two distinct objects to bake texture maps from one to the other. (I also noticed a typo I made above "IV unwrap" should be "UV unwrap")